# Easy way to get mac address of network card

Tags: networking, bash, arch-linux, mac-address

I use a lot of scripts that involve the Mac addresses of my network cards. Is there a file I can read or a command that I can use to JUST get the Mac address? I don't want any headers or anything, just 1 line of output that has the Mac address. I would like to set this as an environment variable on login. I use Arch Linux x64

Comment: Whatever command you normally use to see the MAC address, pipe its output through `awk` (or perl, or ...) and pull out just the bit you want.

Comment: Be aware that the MAC address is not a static unchangable value it used to be.  Pretty much everywhere it is user configurable/changable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 VARIABLE="$(cat /sys/class/net/$IFACE/address)"
```

It's hard to do it simpler.

Well, actually:

```
 read -r MACADDRESS < /sys/class/net/$iFACE/address
```

is even simpler, and starts no additional process.

Comment: `VARIABLE=\`cat /sys/class/net/$IFACE/address\`` also work.

Comment: I knew there had to be a more graceful way than using sed on `ip link show dev $iface`. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Can probably be optimized a bit:

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep -o 'HWaddr  *[0-9A-F:]*' | sed -s 's/HWaddr *//'
```

I don't think you can simplify it much from this. I did an `strace` on the ifconfig, and it seems you pull the MAC addr with an ioctl() on a socket, not from a /proc file.

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated on Linux, in favor of `ip`, which is as easily parsable: `ip link show dev eth0 | sed -nre 's@.*link\/ether (\S+).*@\1@p'`

Comment: Have you figured out a way to do this without regular expressions?